# Space Character showing as symbol in HTML when converting to XML to HTML with XSLT

Tags: vb.net, xslt

I have some code using VB.net to converts XML to HTML file using an XSLT stylesheet.

```
 Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform(True)
 xslt.Load(stylesheet)
 Dim HTMLoutputFile As String = TempDirectory + "test.html"
 If File.Exists(HTMLoutputFile) Then
    File.Delete(HTMLoutputFile)
 End If
 Dim outputStream As New FileStream(HTMLoutputFile, FileMode.Append)
 xslt.Transform(XMLoutputFile, Nothing, outputStream)
 outputStream.Close()
```

THE XLST has `&#160;` to insert white spaces, but when opening the HTML code I get strange characters showing. The character is a black diamond symbol with a question mark in the middle.

I tried using `&#xA0;` in the XSLT, but I get the same thing.

How can I get a whitespace instead of the weird characters?

Part of the XLST

```
<span class="Normal">   
        <xsl:for-each select="//reasons/Addendum">
            <b>Addendum Note</b>&#160;(<xsl:value-of select="sectionEnctInfo/NoteCreator"/>;
            <xsl:value-of select="sectionEnctInfo/datetimeStamp"/>)<br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="multilineNote">
                <xsl:with-param name="theNoteItemNode" select="noteItem"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:if test="noteItem/imageNoteFile != ''">            
                <br/><img src="{noteItem/imageNoteFile}"></img><br/>
            </xsl:if>
            <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </span>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this asked *couple* times... and suggested duplicate... To clarify your post consider to re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code - the XSLT is not really minimal nor complete and post missing desired output...

Comment: I'm not at all convinced this is a duplicate of the question cited.

Comment: @MichaelKay "a HTML or script source file is stored in the wrong encoding" - isn't that exactly what you're saying?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no longer a link to the duplicate that was cited so I can't check it. My recollection is that it was all about use of HTML entities in XML, which I don't think is the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion would be that the XSLT processor is writing the output HTML file using one encoding, and you are opening it for reading using some software that is assuming a different encoding.

Check any encoding specified in an `xsl:output` declaration in the stylesheet; and open the file using a hex editor to see how the characters are actually encoded.

Comment: Here is the the xsl tag: <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

Comment: See what happens if you change it to encoding="uff-8".

Comment: changing the encoding worked!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please click the tick/check mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted. This helps the site classify which questions have been answered.